# How to clear my Symfony project of a deleted entity?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I created an entity "Publishers" with coupls relations.

I wanted to remove this entity and anything related to it. And I have been told to delete the Entity file and Migration file.

Now when I run my website I get the following message :

```
The target-entity App\Entity\Publisher cannot be found in 'App\Entity\Games#publishers'.
```

How can I fix this and "clear" everything that was related to this entity ?

Comment: Have you removed the `$publishers` property contained in the `Games` Entity as showed in the error message? If yes you've to remove also any relation from any file have something related to the `Publisher` Entity (like repository, migration files...), and remember to clear the cache!

Comment: Indead I forgot 1 line of code in the file (and also in another one). Thank you

Is there any other place I should look for removing something to avoid future problems?

Comment: If you don't know/remember where are the relations just read the next error message ;) they will tell you where to give a look exactly.

Comment: also `grep`ing (with `-i`) for the entity name in the `src` directory (and potentially `templates` and `config`) usually helps to find all references to it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to clear your metadata cache:

```
./bin/console doctrine:cache:clear-metadata
```

Doctrine stores this cache using one of the cache drivers: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/caching.html#metadata-cache.
So it could be different from filesystem cache stored in folder.